# Weird situation, define a file path connecting to Access .accdb database in Excel VBA using ADO, however it tells me couldn't find .mdb file

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, ado

I'm writing code in Excel VBA using ADO connection to open an Access .accdb database. I defined the file path as bellow, but when I run my code, error message tells me that "couldn't find file C:\Users\sevenice\Documents\EM Database.mdb". It's so weird that I never define that file path which in .mdb file extent.

However, when I save accdb file as mdb file and then place the mdb file under Documents folder, the code works! But I couldn't figure it out why.

Is there anything wrong with my codes? Or there exists some default file path in Access 2007? My code is in Excel 2007.

Thanks,
Bing

Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset

Dim Dbfilepath As String

```
Dbfilepath = "C:\Users\sevenice\Desktop\EM Database.accdb"

Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection

cnn.Open "Provider= Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & " Data Source=" & Dbfilepath & ";" & "Persist Security Info =False;"

Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
rst.ActiveConnection = cnn
```

Comment: First thing is, you don't need the " & " between the sections of your connection string. Just make it one string and use the & in front of and behind the DbFlePath. Second as onedaywhen said below, Try it with a SQL statement. As in rst.open strsql, cnn, The Access provider is picky about the way the connection string is formed.

Comment: Have you checked whether the variable Dbfilepath isn't defined somewhere else as a Public variable or a Constant?

Answer (score 1):

Are you referencing the database name in your SQL text (which you have snipped from your code as posted)?

e.g.

`SELECT [g/gtop] FROM [EM Database].[N (t) Data]`

AFAIK this syntax will attempt to find a database `EM Database.mdb` in the current directory. I guess it uses .mdb to be compatible with legacy code (or it is a bug! :)